# Multiple subdomains on 1 node.js server

Tags: node.js, express, subdomain

I would like to create a system of multiple web applications (probably around 3-5 node.js + express applications) on one server. I also only have one domain. So I figured that I need to create subdomains for each of my application apart from the main one.

My question is - how do I redirect users coming to certain subdomains to the right application? Do I need to use virtual machines and then redirect each user to a different VM (ip address) depending on their subdomain? How would I even do that?

Or could I just run every application on the same server just with a different port number? Or is there any other way that I'm not really thinking of?

Which way would be the cleanest and how would I implement it?

Comment: front it with a webserver, such as apache or nginx.

Answer (score 2):

A very common way to achieve this is to run each of your node servers on a different port, and then set up a reverse proxy like [nginx](http://nginx.org) to have it forward requests based on matching the host header of incoming HTTP requests.

You could of course handle this manually with node, by checking the `host` header yourself and forwarding each request to the proper node server on the associated port.

Here is some Node code which illustrates what I'm referring to:

```
const http = require('http')
const url = require('url')
const port = 5555
const sites = {
  exampleSite1: 544,
  exampleSite2: 543
}

const proxy = http.createServer( (req, res) => {
  const { pathname:path } = url.parse(req.url)
  const { method, headers } = req
  const hostname = headers.host.split(':')[0].replace('www.', '')
  if (!sites.hasOwnProperty(hostname)) throw new Error(`invalid hostname ${hostname}`)

  const proxiedRequest = http.request({
    hostname,
    path,
    port: sites[hostname],
    method,
    headers 
  })

  proxiedRequest.on('response', remoteRes => {
    res.writeHead(remoteRes.statusCode, remoteRes.headers)  
    remoteRes.pipe(res)
  })
  proxiedRequest.on('error', () => {
    res.writeHead(500)
    res.end()
  })

  req.pipe(proxiedRequest)
})

proxy.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`reverse proxy listening on port ${port}`)
})
```